# Automatic offset adjustment

Tags: operational-amplifier, offset

I have a signal which can have a different offset voltage based on the requirements. However, I need the voltage to start at zero.

[image: normal signal]

Since the offset is variable, I was hoping if there are any techniques/ideas how to design a analog circuit which makes a variable offset in such a way that is ensured that the voltage is always positive (so starting at zero).

I am aware that I might be asking something which is impossible but I hope someone designed something similar.

Comment: not entirely the same, the problem in my application is that I have a easy way to make a trapezoidal signal, however I want to have the flexibility to have a larger fall time than rise time, as a result the signal starts to have negative dc off set, which i need to compensate.

Comment: How fast can the "variable offset" change? It's important to know.

Comment: Is this signal part of a complex waveform, such as NTSC video where the SYNCTIP defined the "zero" voltage?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has been done for over half a century on TV sync pulses that are AC coupled and then DC clamped to the ground on the back porch to set the black level.

The way it works is the leading edge to your desired 0V level is differentiated to trigger a very short pulse and then AC coupled for this "**active clamp circuit."**  It shorts the input signal to ground with an open collector or open drain and charges up the cap with the DC offset voltage. (T=RdsON*C) to the achieve 0V out. then the FET switch is opened until the next leading edge. Obviously, any load current must be minimized by a low bias current, low input offset Buffer to prevent decay and reclamp charge current.

Comment: do you have any reference which  I could use to get a feel of the idea. And will this distort my linear trapezoidal signal?

Comment: not if done right, define distort 1% glitch?  did you not yet search for active clamp cct?  If not, get it done.

Comment: you must define all the variables of the input signal. It would help if you explained why this occurs as there may be a better solution to prevent this

Comment: @Navaro Perhaps here? [Wiki clamp](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clamper_(electronics)). Or did I misunderstand things?

Comment: @Navaro   THey even have an IC for this https://www.diodes.com/assets/Datasheets/ZXFV4089.pdf

Comment: Thanks for all the comments....the circuit in the link provided by @jonk seems to work.

Comment: Ok a diode clamp has negative offset of Vf, while a transistor clamp does not.  Aka DC restorer. It can also be done with an open collector comparator when the input goes below 0V for those types that allow this

Comment: @Navaro It should do a credible job. The one using the opamp will be a little more accurate in developing the ground baseline (the more passive, diode-based one will clamp within about one diode drop of ground, but not much better than that.)

Comment: Personally I prefer the comparator solution with some conditions since it is a large negative voltage, using a diode and a low ESR switch if one knows the source impedance

Comment: Yes indeed Jonk,   I used the op- amp solution in my simulation. I did like the idea  you recommended @TonyEErocketscientist ,  but the other one was simpler to implement. Thanks For your input

Comment: The choice always comes down to your error tolerance which was TBD